# What debian build am I supposed to download?

Tags: debian

I have an i7 6700 processor, and I have no idea how to find out what architecture it is (amd64, arm64, armel, armhf, i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, ppc64el or s390x) in order to choose a matching Debian build. How do I find out? It wasn't listed on Intel's site nor could I find it in a Google search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the information is indeed not easy to find — the architecture you're after is [`amd64`](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch02s01.html.en#idp70939008). Comprehensive information on the different architectures supported in Debian is available on the [Debian ports page](https://www.debian.org/ports/).

Answer (score 1):

You have Intels **i7** brand processor and those are all **x86_64** processors. You can find out this information for example by reading wikipedia article about [core i7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i7) and from article about [x86_64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

The latter article states that **x86_64** is also known as **AMD64**, so you should choose that architecture.